# Extract data from list and order it

Tags: python, extract

Problem statement:

> I have a finite element mesh made of two noded finite elements (so each finite element (line) is made of two nodes located in its extremeties). I have several types of components (groups of finite elements) in the mesh. So for example a vertical component is made up of several finite elements aligned vertically from bottom to top, and adjacent finite elements share a common node.
>
> > I need to get a list of lists where each list has the node IDs (node numbers) of each vertical component, ordered from bottom to top.

What I have:
I have two lists of lists: `nodes` and `elements`
`nodes` and `elements` have the following structures:

```
nodes = [[node_ID1, X1, Y1, Z1],[node_ID2, X2, Y2, Z2], ...]]
elements = [[element_ID1, nodeID_a, nodeID_b],[element_ID2, nodeID_b, nodeID_c], ...]]
```

I also have two other list of lists called `nodesV` and `elementsV` which represent a subset sample of nodes and elements, respectively:

```
nodesV = [[node_IDa, node_IDb, node_IDc],[ ....]]
elementsV = [[element_IDa, element_IDb, element_IDc],[ ....]]
```

These two lists represent the nodes and elements of all vertical components, respectively.

What I need:
Based on the above data I need to build a list of lists where each list contains the ordered nodes IDs of each vertical component:

```
desired_list = [[first nodeID of vertical component 1, ...., last nodeID],[first nodeID of vertical component 2, ...., last nodeID], ...]]
```

Example:
Lets assume that we only have two components in the mesh, each made up of only a single element, and one is vertical:

```
nodes = [[1, 0, 0, 0], [2, 1, 0, 0], [3, 1, 0, 1]]
elements = [[1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 3]]

nodesV = [[1,3]] #each list can only contain 16 elements
elementsV = [[2]]
```

so `desired_list = [[1,3]]`

Any ideas how to do this for a multiple thousand nodes mesh?